# Compute day and night duration in Lebanon in r

Tags: r

I have this data from previous question:

```
dat = structure(list(
  start_time = structure(c(1431096404, 1431107312, 1431124632, 1431163956, 1431170210, 1431180438, 1431225936, 1431431610, 1431434550, 1431450416, 1431457208), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago"), 
  end_time = structure(c(1431104384, 1431119732, 1431126312, 1431168936, 1431179030, 1431193878, 1431240696, 1431432150, 1431447870, 1431455096, 1431465728),
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
  class = "data.frame")
```

The function below was the answer. My question is how to edit the function below to calculate duration in minutes for day and night in Lebanon not Chicago. so the function is:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(suncalc)

calc_in_oneday <- function(st, ed, lon = 0, lat = 0) {
    sunlight_times <- getSunlightTimes(as.Date(st), lat = lat, lon = lon)
    sunset <- sunlight_times$sunset
    sunrise <- sunlight_times$sunrise
    sec_night <- sec_day <- 0

    if(st > sunset | ed<=sunrise) { # when the period includes the night only
        sec_night  <- difftime(ed, st, units = "secs")
    } else if(st > sunrise & ed<=sunset) { # when the period includes the daytime only
        sec_day  <- difftime(ed, st, units = "secs")
    } else { # when things are bit more complicated
        if (st<=sunrise) { # if "start" is before sunrise time until sunrise will be added to night
            sec_night <- sec_night + difftime(sunrise, st, units = "secs")
        } else {  
            # if otherwise time until sunset will be added to daytime 
            # in this condition "end" will come after sunset (otherwise the second condition above will be satisfied)
            sec_day <- sec_day + difftime(sunset, st, units = "secs")
        } 
        if (ed<=sunset) { # The same logic
            sec_day <- sec_day + difftime(ed, sunrise, units = "secs")
        } else {
            sec_night <- sec_night + difftime(ed, sunset, units = "secs")
        } 
        if(st <= sunrise & ed > sunset) { # above will not add the entire daytime when "start" before sunrise and "end" after sunset
            sec_day <- sec_day + difftime(sunset, sunrise, units = "secs")
        }
    }
    sec_night <- unclass(sec_night)
    sec_day <- unclass(sec_day)
    attr(sec_day, "units") <- NULL
    attr(sec_night, "units") <- NULL
    return(list(sec_day = sec_day, sec_night = sec_night))
}
```

The nested conditions are complicated. I believe it is right but please check by yourself.

For multiple days

Using the function above, deal with the check for multiple days period. What this function does is check whether the start and end date, and if these are not the same, calculate the day/night time until the end of the first date, and then slide the start time to the beginning of the next day. (Edit: the tzone of the start/end time).

```
calc_day_night <- function(st, ed, lon = 0, lat = 0) {
    attr(st, "tzone") <- "UTC"
    attr(ed, "tzone") <- "UTC"

    sec_night <- sec_day <- 0
    while(as.Date(st) != as.Date(ed)) {
        tmp_ed <- as.Date(st) + days(1)
        day_night_oneday <- calc_in_oneday(st, tmp_ed, lon, lat)
        sec_night <- sec_night + day_night_oneday$sec_night
        sec_day <- sec_day + day_night_oneday$sec_day
        st <- tmp_ed
    }
    day_night_oneday <- calc_in_oneday(st, ed, lon, lat)
    sec_night <- sec_night + day_night_oneday$sec_night
    sec_day <- sec_day + day_night_oneday$sec_day
    return(list(sec_day = sec_day, sec_night = sec_night))
}
```

Test
Using the test data, the results look like this:

```
dat %>%  
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(temp = list(calc_day_night(start_time, end_time, lat = 41, lon = -85))) %>%
    mutate(sec_day = temp$sec_day) %>%
    mutate(sec_night = temp$sec_night) %>%
    mutate(min_day = round(sec_day / 60)) %>%
    mutate(min_night = round(sec_night / 60)) %>%
    select(-matches("sec")) %>%
    select(-temp)
```